# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: dpkg

I've just run:

> sudo apt-get upgrade

And at the end I get the following error:

```
Setting up liboxideqtquick0:amd64 (1.4.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 (1.4.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
 update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have try to made an update of your dpkg?

```
sudo apt-get update dpkg
```

Comment: sudo apt-get update dpkg

E: The update command takes no arguments

Comment: Oh yea sorry my bad, try to do an update: sudo apt-get update .After this try to do an upgrade of your dpkg: sudo apt-get upgrade dpkg